# .reloadData() and .setNeedsDisplay() are being ignored

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a pagination tool from a toolbar that hits this method :

```
func nextPage(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let currentChapter = page.valueForKey("chapter") as! Int
    let appDelegate    = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest   = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Page")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(chapter = %d)", currentChapter + 1)
    do {
        let result = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)



        // It is here, I can clearly see we have the old object.

        self.page = result[0] as! NSManagedObject

        // And here I can clearly see that a new object was set.



        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print(fetchError)
    }
}
```

This method is located in my UIViewController that is set up like so :

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class PageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

// Mark: Properties

var page:             NSManagedObject!
var tableView       = UITableView()
var toolBar         = UIToolbar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.frame                     = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height - 50)
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight        = 200
    tableView.rowHeight                 = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.scrollEnabled             = true
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled    = true
    tableView.delegate                  = self
    tableView.dataSource                = self
    tableView.tableHeaderView           = containerView

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

Any ideas why my `tableView` is not reloading its new data?

---

**Update**

As recommended by @Koder and @Simon, I updated my code as so.. but the UI still did not update :

```
func nextPage(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let currentChapter = page.valueForKey("chapter") as! Int
    let appDelegate    = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest   = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Page")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(chapter = %d)", currentChapter + 1)
    do {
        let result = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        self.page = result[0] as! NSManagedObject
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        }

    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print(fetchError)
    }
}
```

Per LucaD's recommendation, I'll also include my `numberOfRows` and `numberOfSections` :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.total
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `is not reloading its new data`. Model is the same or, even if the model isn't the same, the data source's methods aren't called?

Comment: @LucaD I mean that the UI is not updating with new content. The `page` attribute is definitely set to the new data. And these two methods are called, but the UI remains the same.

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSection` methods are called?

Comment: @LucaD Yes, I updated my answer above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fire all the UI refreshing code on the main thread.
For updating tableView, try firing the below from the background thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
{
self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

this code block will asynchronously get executed on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I updated my answer with what I assume is a correct implementation of your idea, but it still doesn't' work.

Comment: I should add that `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are indeed being called, so I'm assuming the `reloadData()` function is working.. but the content in the UI doesn't actually update.

Comment: Ah ok I got it. It was because I wasn't writing the data directly, but hardcoding it elsewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you need to move that code into the main thread: UI changes performed in background threads won't update the screen. Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
{
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Simon

Comment: Interesting. But where would I put this? I tried throwing it in my fetchRequest and other methods, but I'm likely not understanding this method yet. Thanks so much for the recommend

Comment: Just wrap the existing code in my `dispatch_async`. This makes the methods you call execute in the main thread which is where UI changes need to happen.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for your support. I updated my answer above with what I think is what you're suggesting, but it doesn't seem to work still. Maybe I'm not implementing it correctly? Thanks anyway!